# Validation rule to show text box

Tags: apex

For Example
My checkbox is = Ck_c
and my Text box is = Tx_c

I want to do like that when check box is checked only then textbox become visible otherwise it remain hide.

How can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you add a code snippet, we can help you do that

Comment: vote up this IDEA https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BroxAAC -- 68000+ votes so you are not the only one requesting this

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in a validation rule. To control whether a textbox is visible or not, you would probably need to use visualforce. Within the component that you use for the field you would use the rendered attribute and enter the conditions to render.

Here is an example of an "IF" condition within a "rendered" attribute:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
 <apex:pageBlock title="Your Output">
  <apex:pageBlockSection title="Your Title">
<apex:outputField rendered="{!IF(!account.LIS_Used__c =
false, false, true)}" value="{!account.Name}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!account.Owner.Name}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
 </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Validation rules cannot be used to hide / unhide other fields. You would need to turn to Visualforce for that type of requirement.

You could use a validation rule to prevent modifications of the field when the checkbox is not checked.

You could potentially use a formula to show the contents of the text box only when the checkbox is checked but the text box would need to be displayed at some point or on a layout to allow for entry.